# component exception error when run on device

Tags: react-native

I got an error in my react native app [image: error]

my application is works fine when run on web browser, but when I try to run it on my android device, the error is appearing on my screen. I'm still beginner in react native sorry if my question is confusing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry my bad, this error caused because I'm using the reactjs library inside my react native app